# Tested with seatool tests like S.M.A.R.T check and short generic passed while long generic and short drive self test fails

Tags: hard-drive

I don't really know if this is either good or bad, but what in the title says my HDD fails on two tests and passes on 2 tests. I am not really sure if it is either good to use or bad to use and needed to be replaced. What do you think? I have a WDC WD5000AAKX-75U6AA0 (500GB) and to mention, it also stops randomly and while I am playing games like Detroit: Become Human, the game crashes and everything from the game freezes and goes like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPgcY.png

So, what do I need to do. Should I Replace it or keep it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Any failing disk drive tests are bad.  You should consider the drive failing and likely to catastrophically fail.  This isn't like a class in school where you can fail 50% of the tests and still pass.

Comment: what are the specific test failures? have you tried verifying with any other test tools like CrystalDiskInfo?

Answer (score -2):

If your game fails on any SMART test it should be replaced immediately.

Backup your data NOW!

Comment: @AlexxWasHere: Don't pay attention to the downvote - replace this disk.